# Data structure for efficient search

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++17

I am looking for a suggestion for the appropriate data structure to use in the following scenario
I have minimum value and maximum value defined for keys for eg.

```
Key          Min Value                Max Value

key1          0 .5                    4.5
key2          1                       9
key3          0.75                    1.5
```

I have to break each value to further sub buckets such that the difference between a minimum value and maximum value can’t exceed 1 and each bucket minimum value will be incremented by 0.5.

for e.g. key1 will break down further

```
Key               Bucket   Min Value                Max Value
key1             B1       0.5                      1.5
key1             B2       1                        2
key1             B3       1.5                      2.5
key1             B4       2                        3
key1             B5       2.5                      3.5
key1             B6       3                        4
key1             B7       3.5                      4.5
```

Once I have these buckets created(which is just one time), I need to find eligible buckets for a given key and value.

For e.g. eligible buckets for key1 and 2.2 are  B3  and B4.

currently, I am storing all the bucket in `std::map<Key, std::vector<Buckets> >`

where Buckets is struct having bucket name, min and max as a variable.

What another alternative I can use than `std::map<Key, std::vector<Buckets> >` to speed up my search process?

Comment: If your `map` is very large and won't be updated very often you could consider replacing it with an `unordered_map` which might provide faster lookups by `Key`. And in this case where the buckets are guaranteed to be in increments of `0.5` you can immediately find the index within the `vector<Bucket>` from `2 * int(value - min_value)` . And as with any optimization, make sure you profile it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place all the records into a `std::vector`, then use `std::map<key, vector-index>`.  This is known as creating an index table.

For small amounts of data, a linear search is not distinguishable from using index tables (actually may be faster).

Search the internet for "first normal form", for ways to optimize your data.

Answer (score 1):

A linear search of a `std::vector` on its own (or `std::binary_search` if it is sorted) performs *surprisingly* well on modern hardware. The contiguous memory layout is very friendly to cache hierarchies and the prefetcher. `std::vector` usually beats the node based containers that have to chase pointers all over memory (even though something like BigO would tell you it would loose big). But, you always have to benchmark different solutions for your specific use case, to know for sure.